# How to get row/column header to print on each new page

Tags: reporting-services, landscape, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Just a little background on what I'm doing as this is not a typical tablix set up.

I am designing a page that prints the cell values vertically because I need it to be in landscape and not portrait. I know I can select report type to change from portrait to landscape but the report has a mix of both portrait and landscape oriented pages within it.

I do not believe report builder can do both in one report, (I'd be happy if I am incorrect in this fact - please let me know) so therefore I am resorting to designing the landscape page vertically in portrait mode, so that the landscape pages can be included in the report that is printed in portrait mode.

To clarify, I have successfully had "column headers?" printed on each new page in portrait pages but never tried doing it using the "row headers?" in this type of situation.

Below is an example of what I want the report to look like but unfortunately I have not found a way to do that in report builder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMYJn.png)

I thought for awhile about how to build a landscape page in report builder that only lets you do all the pages in portrait or landscape. So to achieve this, I am converting the landscape page in a portrait oriented environment. I've taken the following steps:

1. Using the property "WritingMode" and setting that to "Rotate270". - This prints all the text vertically.

Everything seems fine except I cannot get the headers to repeat on a new page.

I am a little confused on this part, perhaps someone with more experience can explain this to me better... is the cells in blue that I want to repeat on each new page considered column headers or row headers?

2. I've tried setting the two static row cells to "Repeat on new page" found in the bottom left corner of the "Advanced  Mode" but that doesn't seem to get the "Steps + Location" headers to print on the new page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IhrD.png)

This shows the output but the page breaks do not include the column header in blue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRZVb.png)

I've also tried to set the static cell in the column group under the advanced mode to "RepeatOnNewPage" but I get this error when I do that.

### The tablix 'Tablix2' has an invalid TablixMember. All TablixMember elements in a TablixColumnHierarchy must have the RepeatOnNewPage property set to false.

### The definition of the report '' is invalid.

An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, just a word of warning. I would look for another approach entirely, even if you manage to get it to render on screen OK then assuming you are exporting to another format (e.g. PDF) you might find that does not render the results in the same way. I've seen many people try and fail. I would look at outputting each section into separate files and then combining them again at the end. If it's PDF for instance, there are plenty of open source libraries you could use to build something.